# How to design the solution to process large population of records in CRM 2016 onPrem?

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking for a best solution to address one business need. Business needs to send SMSs  to customer's to participate in the Poll.

In CRM we have a custom entity to control SMS content, URL and reminder and an external database to manage the transactions.

From CRM side I need to process all records and update the SMS content and Shorten the URL and update the same to an external database. To shorten the url using 3rd party api.

My ask is how to design the solution which can process millions of records without any issue, Which one will be better Console app or Workflow ?

How to avoid performance issue, If I put this much population in a foreach loop/parallel foreach loop  to process the records with following actions -
1. Perform update on CRM entity record
2. Calling 3rd party api to get shorten url in response & updating in CRM entity
3. Updating some flags and SMS Content in an external database.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually been through a similar situation as you are and the best advice I can give you is externalize all the business logic you can to another system/process, all the heavy work should be done outside Dynamics 365.

This is how I solved the problem:

1. Created a *SMS Message* custom entity like you did in dynamics with all the information needed to send a text message (phone number, message, status, etc.).
2. Implemented an Async Post Create plugin that would send all this information to an Azure Service Bus queue. Async is really important here so that Dynamics is blocked as few as possible. This plugin should be as light as possible and have no business logic whatsoever.
3. Created an Azure function to be triggered when a new message is received by the queue. This Azure function did all the business logic I needed which was mainly an integration with a SMS Gateway. In your case, it can call the 3rd party API to shorten url, integrate with the external database, etc. Lastly, update the Sms Message record with the shorten url and other info that you need.

A few more notes

- You can easily scale up most Azure services if you feel like your process needs a boost in performance, which is a major advantage vs. having it being processed inside dynamics.
- In step 2, you can achieve this logic with a [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-webhooks) as well.
- The higher throughput you need the more you should consider to replace step 2 and 3 with a WebJob, that recursively searches and fetches all Sms Messages in Dynamics that still need to be processed (you can control this with a status *to be processed* for example) and then does all the logic you need, as in step 3.

Comment: Thanks for response,

Comment: Thanks for response, Unfortunately I am restricted to develop console for this. Did you provide any functionality to define SMS template where business can compose their SMSs and insert any field from contact and that populates in the actual message according to the Contact record, I mean same functionality like Email Template where we insert dynamic values like {!EntityLogicalName:FieldLogicalName;}. Please suggest any OOB or lighter way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement a console application that recursively fetches SMS Messages that need to be processed from Dynamics, call the 3rd party API to shorten url, integrate with the external database, just like the step 3 of my answer. To make it run recursively search how to run Console Application Using Windows Scheduler. Regarding email templates that's a different question from the one you have asked in the first place, please open a new topic if you need help with it.